# Setting citation_package option under pdf_document in YAML Header and using rmarkdown::pdf_document function

Tags: r-markdown

[The help file of the](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/rmarkdown.pdf) `pdf_document` function of the **Rmarkdown** CRAN package says that the function is defined with the following options:

```
pdf_document(toc = FALSE, toc_depth = 2, number_sections = FALSE,
  fig_width = 6.5, fig_height = 4.5, fig_crop = TRUE,
  fig_caption = TRUE, dev = "pdf", df_print = "default",
  highlight = "default", template = "default", keep_tex = FALSE,
  latex_engine = "pdflatex", citation_package = c("none", "natbib",
  "biblatex"), includes = NULL, md_extensions = NULL,
  pandoc_args = NULL, extra_dependencies = NULL)
```

I am under the impression that I could add any of these arguments as options under pdf_document in the output section of the YAML header in my Rmarkdown document. Is this correct? The document managed to compile when I used the following options/arguments of pdf_document: `toc`, `number_sections`, `fig_caption`, `df_print`, and `keep_tex`. However, when I add `citation_package` to the list, I get an error in compiling. For instance, consider the following template Rmarkdown document.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Unknown"
date: "4/18/2019"
output:  
  pdf_document:
    # toc: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    df_print: kable
    keep_tex: true
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: sample_bib.bib
csl: /Users/Shared/Zotero/styles/multidisciplinary-digital-publishing-institute.csl
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown
I love R [@rcoreteamLanguageEnvironmentStatistical2018].
````

The `sample_bib.bib` mentioned is the bib file that looks like

```
@software{rcoreteamLanguageEnvironmentStatistical2018,
  location = {{Vienna, Austria}},
  title = {R: {{A Language}} and {{Environment}} for {{Statistical Computing}}},
  url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
  version = {3.5.1},
  organization = {{R Foundation for Statistical Computing}},
  date = {2018},
  author = {{R Core Team}}
}
```

However, I was unable to knit this Rmarkdown document. I got the following error.

```
/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS rmarkdown_pdf_document.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output rmarkdown_pdf_document.tex --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --number-sections --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --biblatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes' 
output file: rmarkdown_pdf_document.knit.md

INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'rmarkdown_pdf_document.blg'
INFO - Reading 'rmarkdown_pdf_document.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'sample\_bib.bib' for section 0
ERROR - Cannot find 'sample\_bib.bib'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
Error: Failed to build the bibliography via biber
Execution halted
Warning message:
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'rcoreteamLanguageEnvironmentStatistical2018' on page 1
 undefined on input line 137.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 169.
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `rmarkdown_pdf_document.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                rmarkdown_pdf_document
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Luckily, this problem is easily fixed by moving the "citation_package" from an option under pdf_document to a separate line in the YAML header. Or:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Unknown"
date: "4/18/2019"
output:  
  pdf_document:
    # toc: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    df_print: kable
    keep_tex: true
citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: sample_bib.bib
csl: /Users/Shared/Zotero/styles/multidisciplinary-digital-publishing-institute.csl
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown
I love R [@rcoreteamLanguageEnvironmentStatistical2018].
````

Upon knitting this adjusted Rmarkdown document, the result is a pdf_document.

**So my question is:** Was I right that you could add any of the arguments found in the pdf_document help file on CRAN as options under "pdf_document" in the YAML header in a Rmarkdown file? Or, upon using this particular `citation_package` argument/option, could this be a possible bug in the `rmarkdown::pdf_document`() function?

[ALSO POSTED ON **RMARKDOWN's** GITHUB](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1573); see for additional comments.

Comment: I have seen this bug several times and it is not correct, that removing the indents will lead to the right result because when you have a look at the pandoc command, you will see that `pandoc-citeproc` (which is the default value) is used and not `biblatex`.

Comment: Nevertheless, did you try to remove the `_`? E.g. name your bib-file `samplebib.bib`, change it in your RMD file and try again.

Comment: @J_F: I will report this for Yihui Xie and the other authors of **rmarkdown** CRAN package to examine more closely. Thank you.

Comment: @J_F,  thank you for confirming my suspicions. I never thought that having an underscore in the bib filename would matter. Upon removing the "_" from `samplebib.bib` when `citation_package` is under `pdf_document` , the document does knit, but I receive these familiar warnings: ```Warning message:
Package biblatex Warning: No driver for entry type 'software'.
(biblatex)                Using fallback driver on input line 198.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.```

Comment: @phargart the warning you see from biblatex means that `@software` you put in your bib file is not recognize by biblatex. There is no entry type software: https://www.openoffice.org/bibliographic/bibtex-defs.html  

The fact you need to remove  `_`, does it work with a underscore with latex only (without any Rmarkdonw ?) I am not sure there is an issue with rmarkdown  

And I agree with @J_F that removing the indent does not solve issue at all.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, the issue was resolved when I reinstalled the  **tinytex** package.          
 Important notes/lessons for other users:
1. Although I didn't have a problem with underscore here,  underscore may not be supported in the bib names, and it is suggested to remove them. 
2. biblatex does not recognize @software ... and you are right. The option to cite something as "software" came from the bibLaTex extension of Zotero reference management software.